# Apache Camel Restlet Producer body key

Tags: rest, apache-camel

i have a problem to get the body over a restlet. My route in Apache Camel is:

```
from("timer:msgGen?period=2000")
    .setBody(simple("A Test"))
    .to("restlet:http://localhost:8888/?restletMethod=POST");
```

localhost:8888 is fiddler. (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

The Rest-Response on fiddler is:

```
A%20Test&breadcrumbId=ID-W530-60491-1415112773228-0-11&firedTime=Tue%20Nov%2004%2015%3A53%3A06%20CET%202014
```

encoded to better read:

```
A Test&breadcrumbId=ID-W530-60491-1415112773228-0-11&firedTime=Tue Nov 04 15:53:06 CET 2014
```

But i think is must be:

```
body=A Test&breadcrumbId=ID-W530-60491-1415112773228-0-11&firedTime=Tue Nov 04 15:53:06 CET 2014
```

The key "body" is missing, or am I misinformed?

Is it a Bug or a Feature? How can i solve this? To get a Key-Value Pair?

Thank you

Comment: You didn't set the response which is start with body.  Camel restlet producer won't add the body= there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem:

```
from("timer:msgGen?period=2000")
    .setBody(simple("A Test"))
    .to("http4://localhost:8888/");
```

This Maven Dependencies you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for help